# How to download a website recursively which is behind Google auth?

Tags: google-chrome, website, browser-addons, web-crawler

I want to download a website recursively that is behind Google auth. I found lots of links in the Chrome store that allow me to download the currently open webpage, but none of them follow links.

Any tips? wget and desktop apps wont work since it cannot authenticate using Google I guess...